# VLC plugin IE 9 bug

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, vlc

I include VLC plugin for IE 9 in such way

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<object width='800' height='600' classid='clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921'>
<param name='src' value='rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/realtime_18831eda-47a6-4633-9431-b8d3c06f943d' />
<param name='autoplay' value='true'/>
<param name='toolbar' value='true' />
</object>
<![endif]-->
```

When page is loaded, it seem that VLC plugin is working (rtsp-stream starts) but VLC is invisible. For make it visible I must make browser window to be redrawn. (for example to scroll or scale browser window). After It VLC becomes visible.

Is any way to solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is that the best way to show a video or live stream. I wouldn't use any VLC plugins to show video. There must be other way to show livestream. Just search [rtsp live stream with flash player html](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=rtsp%20live%20stream%20with%20flash%20player%20html). Also I recommend to use [embed](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp) tag instead of object and param. Happy times to code.

Comment: And BTW. Internet Explorer sucks. I'm just saying.